# spark UDF to return list of Rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In spark SQL I am trying to join multiple table those are already in place.
How ever i need to use a function which will take user input and then get details from two other tables,then use this result in the join.
The query is some thing like below
    select  t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col3,cast((t1.value * t3.value) from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2 on t1.col = t2.col
    left join fn_calculate (value1, value2) as t3 on t1.value = t3.value

here fn_calculate is the function which is taking value1,value2 as parameters and then that function returns a table of rows.(in SQL server that is returning Table)

I am trying to do this by using hive generic UDF which will take the input param and then return the dataframe? like below

```
public String evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments) throws HiveException {
    if (arguments.length != 1) {
        return null;
    }
    if (arguments[0].get() == null) {
        return null;
    }
    DataFrame dataFrame = sqlContext
            .sql("select * from A where col1 = value and col2 =value2");
    javaSparkContext.close();
    return "dataFrame";
}
```

or the scala functions do i need use like below?

```
static class Z extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0<DataFrame> { 

    @Override`enter code here`
public DataFrame apply() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
return sqlContext.sql("select * from A where col1 = value and col2  
     =value2");
}
}
```

Comment: Please illustrate question with data,code and expected output.

Comment: @mtoto explained with more details, thx

Comment: I am actually not getting the question properly , but it seems that there would be a better way to do the same thing without using the udf to generate t3 inside the query as you have mentioned , as UDF(i ma talking abt spark sql UDF) will work row by row, and will return a row only , even if you are trying to return list of things , it can return it in an array datatype but the join that has been mentioned works between the tables and not the row and a table . So, i think a better way should include generating t3 earlier and then using that in this query.

Comment: It could be that i understood the question wrongly..so please correct me if i am getting wrong idea..but this seems to be the case based on my limited knowledge